# Entity Framework Include method

Tags: entity-framework, include

[image]

when i try to use include i can't access to table context.Users, only to it's fields

Where is my mistake?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Load method means you are some how trying to use Eager loading of certain requirements, what you could try and do is turn off Lazy Loading, this way all queries will load related entities without having to use the Include Method. They proxy entities will handle the references between the entity relationships for you.

Once you return Doctors in your View, and you loop through them

```
foreach(var doctor in Model) {   @doctor.PhoneNumber.EmergencyNumber }
```

PhoneNumber will be proxied by EF and you will not need to use any Eager Loading through the Include function.

```
public Context() : base("DefaultConnection")
{
    Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true; // Our Navigational Properties
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; // No need to Include with Eager Loading
    Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true; // Change Tracker for changes made on either side of the Association through Proxy Class
    Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true; // Validate On Saving for Data Integrity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use context.Doctor.Include(d=>d.PhoneNumbers)

this will extract all doctors with filled phone numbers per each

Comment: i can't include all table? just fields?